# How can I pass a powershell variable into a CMD command?

Tags: variables, powershell, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to run the following command through powershell:

```
schtasks /query /s $compname /v /fo csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

$compname is set in the first part of the powershell script, but cannot be passed into the command like this. For example, when I try passing in $localhost, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Value expected for '/s'.
Type "SCHTASKS /QUERY /?" for usage.
```

Is there a way to pass the variable into this command? I don't plan to change to powershell's native way to access scheduled tasks (through a COM object).

Comment: Did you mean localost (without the dollar sign). It works for me

Comment: @ShayLevy no, I'm not trying to use localhost, I was just using that as an example. I have a variable ($compname) that is set in a powershell script. Is there a way to use the value of that variable in the schtasks command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working for me, tested in v2. Does it help if you enclose the variable in double quotes (e.g "$compname") ?

```
$compname = 'localhost'
schtasks /query /s $compname /v /fo csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Comment: I do schtasks the same way in one of my scripts with variables and it works for me as well...OP should make sure `$compname` actually has a value when it gets to that line.

Comment: I think what @SpellingD said is right, it must not have had a value. It seems to be working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "schtasks /query /s $compname /v /fo csv" | ConvertFrom-Csv
```