# ForEach-Object $_ Variable not working as expected

Tags: powershell, foreach-object

I am trying to get the real names of each user in an AD group, I have created it to the point of getting the output to show the User IDs of each member in the group but then trying to do a `net user $_ /domain` on each user in the .txt file it gives me errors like there is nothing there. Before the onslaught of "why dont you just use Get-AD*" I understand that its out there, but we cannot install that module here. I need something other people can use without installing things.

I have tried a few ways to approach this and the below code is the part of the script that doesnt seem to be working correctly. I have the other way I tried it commented out but left it there as another possible starting point.

```
function Return-DropDown {
    $Choice = $DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()
    if ($Choice)
        {
        net group $Choice /domain > C:\Temp\RawOut.txt

        $UserID = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\RawOut.txt'
        $UserID[($UserID.IndexOf('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------') + 1) .. ($UserID.IndexOf('The command completed successfully.') -1)] > C:\Temp\RawIDs.txt

        Start C:\Temp\RawIDs.txt

        Remove-Item C:\Temp\RawOut.txt

        Get-Content -path C:\Temp\RawIDs.txt | ForEach-Object {net user $_ /domain | findstr "Full Name"} >> C:\Temp\$Choice+RealNames.txt
        #$RealNames = Get-Content -path C:\Temp\RawIDs.txt
        #ForEach ($_ in $RealNames) 
        #{
           # net user $_ /domain >> C:\Temp\$Choice+1.txt

           # }

        }

}
```

What I am getting back is:

```
net : The syntax of this command is:
At C:\Users\MyID\OneDrive - MyCompany\AD Group DropDown.ps1:34 char:64
+ ... path C:\Temp\RawIDs.txt | ForEach-Object {net user $_ /domain} >> C:\ ...
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The syntax of this command is::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

NET USER
[username [password | *] [options]] [/DOMAIN]
         username {password | *} /ADD [options] [/DOMAIN]
         username [/DELETE] [/DOMAIN]
         username [/TIMES:{times | ALL}]
         username [/ACTIVE: {YES | NO}]
```

Let me know any advice for getting this function to work.

Comment: `NET` is not a PowerShell command; it's implemented as an EXE file. You can't use it in the pipe; you'll have to assign to a non-pipe variable and pass it as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462020/how-can-i-pass-a-powershell-variable-into-a-cmd-command

Comment: I tried this with the commented out section using `ForEach ($Line in $RealNames) {net user $Line /domain} ` but this also kicks back the same error.

Comment: In your commented-out section, do _not_ use `$_` as the variable name; it's not valid outside the pipe. Change it to `$UserID` or something.

Comment: I understand, I tried using `$Line` in replacement of `$_` and it doesnt work.

Comment: [Related](https://superuser.com/questions/1277062/sort-net-group-output-in-one-column) see the ***not*** accepted [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1277178/639112).

Comment: Thank you @LotPings, That pointed me in the direction to find my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @LotPings for helping me out with finding a solution.

I discovered (through looking at a post LotPings commented) that I was getting the output in a format that was causing an error. My txt file was formatted:

```
User1               User2               User3
User4               User5               User6
...
```

And it was trying to take the full line `User1               User2               User3` as the variable. Which was obviously not working. with using a `-replace` and `-split` to get the format right for my variable and it's working now.

```
function Return-DropDown {
    $Choice = $DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()
    if ($Choice)
        {
        net group $Choice /domain > C:\Temp\RawOut.txt

        $UserID = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\RawOut.txt'
        $UserID[($UserID.IndexOf('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------') + 1) .. ($UserID.IndexOf('The command completed successfully.') -1)] > C:\Temp\RawIDs.txt

        #Start C:\Temp\RawIDs.txt

        Remove-Item C:\Temp\RawOut.txt

        $results = Get-Content -path C:\Temp\RawIDs.txt

            foreach($result in $results) { 
                ($result -replace '\s+',',') -split ',' | ? { $_ } >> 'C:\temp\users.txt'
                }

        Get-Content -path C:\Temp\users.txt | ForEach-Object {net user $_ /domain | findstr "Full Name"} >> C:\Temp\$Choice.txt

        Remove-Item C:\Temp\users.txt
        Remove-Item C:\Temp\RawIDs.txt
        Start C:\Temp\$Choice.txt
        }

}
```